# git stash - prevent a misspelled subcommand from executing

Tags: git, git-stash

In the [`git stash` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-push-p--patch-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--ltpathspecgt82308203), there is this paragraph:

> For quickly making a snapshot, you can omit "push". **In this mode, non-option arguments are not allowed to prevent a misspelled subcommand from making an unwanted stash entry**. The two exceptions to this are stash -p which acts as alias for stash push -p and pathspecs, which are allowed after a double hyphen -- for disambiguation.

What exactly does the highlighted sentence mean?
The only non-option arguments that I think can be used are `<message>` and `<pathspec>...`.

Does it mean that if one writes the command `git stash -m"message"`, git may think that the user misspelled the word `stash`, but it executes the command (`git stash push`) anyway?

Thank you.

Comment: I initially misread the highlighted sentence. I believe it should be read as: "[In this mode, non-option arguments are not allowed] (in order) [to prevent a misspelled subcommand from making an unwanted stash entry.]"

Comment: However, why is `stash -p` an exception? Isn't `-p` an option argument?

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, it's linked to the typical behaviour of `git stash save`.

If you do

```
git stash save whatever you want
```

then every argument ('whatever', 'you', and 'want') will be taken as a whole to compose the stash message. (note : `stash save` is deprecated)

Now, as `git stash push` allows omitting `push`, the statement you quote in bold is making "clear" (obviously, not enough) that the behaviour we just saw about `git stash save` does NOT apply. Other non-option arguments are not allowed here.

In short, an example of what we cannot do :

```
git stash whatever I want
```

where `push` would be implied after `stash`.

Or more specifically (to address the "misspelling" part) :

```
# next command will create a new branch with the last stashed content
git stash branch myNewBranch

# and the next WOULD HAVE created a new stash entry with message "brnach myNewBranch"
# if not for the part you quoted in bold
git stash brnach myNewBranch
```

**Edit after comments :** But then this last misspelled line will just be rejected in error instead of stashing anything inadvertantly.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer. However, I believe that there are no non-option arguments that do not come after an option argument (for example, you must write -m or --message before <message>). Also, why do they list `-p` as an exception? Isn't `-p` an option argument?

Comment: I think it reads "If you include `-p` then the rule does not apply any more", which makes sense since you explicitly stated the main command to execute (push) then non-option arguments can be passed to form the message. But I'm with you to say it's very oddly formulated...

Comment: Ok, I believe you are right. But I think you must use -m or --message before the message, no? The only non-option arguments that are not related to an option argument are the items in `<pathspec>...`.

Comment: So, given the current version of git (2.17.0), in the example at the end of your post, it should have been "# and the next WOULD HAVE created a new stash entry with only the files "brnach" and "myNewBranch" ", right?

Comment: @user42768 When I said "it WOULD HAVE created a new stash entry with message..." I was implying "... if `git stash push` did behave like `git stash save`"

Comment: I understand. But given the way `git stash push` behaves, I guess the bolded sentence of my quote is only necessary due to the `<pathspec>...` non-option argument.